# "..., nie ohne etwas Neues zu erfinden." -- Bedeutung?

Tags: meaning, negation

> Meine Großmutter erzählte uns Kindern Geschichten, nie ohne etwas Neues zu erfinden.<sup>*</sup>

Was bedeutet der Satz genau? Hat sie jedes Mal etwas Neues erfunden? Oder hat sie  niemals etwas Neues erfunden?

Ich habe hier Probleme mit der doppelten Negation.

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Monika Reimann: Grundstufen-Grammatik, S. 233. 44/4</sub>

Comment: Are you sure about the placement of the comma?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I am not sure I follow. If your question is about the quoted sentence, then yes, it is how it is written in the book (I have double-checked).

Comment: Yes, it was about the original sentence, where I think the placement of the comma is a bit strange. I'd have written *Meine Großmutter ... Geschichten nie, ohne etwas Neues zu erfinden*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Well, that is how it is in the book. Triple-checked. Interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never did she tell stories without inventing something new = she invented something new every time.

Answer (score 1):

You can translate the sentence like that:
"My grandmother told us children stories. And never did it without inventing something new"

In German double negations can (unlike in English) eliminate themselves. If you do something "nie ohne" you do it always.

Comment: Unlike in English? Siehe Ingmars Übersetzung.

Comment: Exactly like english, dont confuse him

Comment: *Nie ohne* is not exactly a double negation. And it is exactly the same as *never without* in English, so I don't agree with the last sentence of your answer.